# How to validate that only one user can be a guardian?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

How should I write validation that only one user can be a guardian.
I am using rails 3.2

**Model**

```
class User
  validate :only_one_guardian

  def only_one_guardian
    if User.where(guardian: true).count > 0
      errors.add( :company_id, 'we already have a guardian')
    end
  end
```

Comment: Let me clarify the relationship between `Company`, `User` and 'guardian'. Do you mean that you want to establish and validate that `Company` `has_one` `User`, who is the 'guardian' for that company?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
 validates :guardian,:uniqueness=>true,:if=>:guardian?
```